# React-Native app can build for debugging but not for archiving

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to archive my iOS app which works fine when I build for debugging via xcode but when I try to archive the app I get the following errors which I'm not sure what's causing it [image]

Comment: maybe the problem is that you didnt generate the main.jsbundle which is required for archive. Try to run the following command: $react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/ConstructionCloud/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'

and then retry the archiveing

Answer (score 0):

I think the real reason for failure would be a little above in the listing, which cannot be seen here.

I had similar kind of issue when updated react native to version 0.54.2 the iOS archive stopped working. 
My error message was something like:

```
A problem occurred while trying to fetch the minifier. Path: "metro-minify-uglify" Cannot find module 'uglify-es'
```

And the problem was that my react native project only had uglify-js in node-modules (I quess that the new react native needed the uglify-es). So I installed that with:

```
npm install uglify-es --save
```

And after that I did (not sure if these are needed) xCode->clean project, shutdown xCode, delete Library->Developer->Xcode->DerivedData, restart Xcode and archive started working again.